# Computing the reduced norm of a central simple algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

I'm trying to compute the reduced norm of a central simple algebra of dimension $n^2$. Right now I'm constructing an $n^2$ matrix $M_x$ as described [here](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~elkies/M250.01/reduced.html), then computing and factoring its determinant.

So the first question I have is:
Given a homogenous multivariate polynomial $g$ of degree $n^2$, which can be written as $f^n$, how can I efficiently find $f$?

I tried general factoring algorithms.
I tried writing $f$ with unknown coeffiecients, then expanding, comparing coefficients with $g$ and solving the system of equations.
I also tried computing the derivative $g'$ with respect to some variable, then computing $g_2:=\gcd(g, g')$, repeating this process until I arrive $f$.
While all methods work, they are too slow for my application.

The second question I have:
Are there ways of computing the reduced norm besides computing and factoring the determinant of an $n^2$ matrix.

Comment: This is very simple if you know that the algebra has a standard involution (i.e. it's a quadratic extension or a quaternion algebra :) ) You don't, do you?

Comment: Indeed, I do not know that :)